# Multiple domain tracking with an iframe - landing page showing up as iframe source in GA

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, google-analytics

So we have website A www.domaina.com and within this website there is an iframe that is shown on all pages, which has source from website B www.domainb.com.

I have setup cross domain tracking using the following code, and if test in GA real time going between the 2 sites, it is correctly showing there is only 1 visitor always. But the landing page (and active page if viewing in Real time) is showing up as the iframe source. I can see this is because using GA debugger, there are multiple tracking beacons being sent out as soon as you land on the home page, and the last one is from the iframe, showing the referring URL being www.domaina.com and the page being domainb.com. THis hence is causing self referrals to show up..

here is the code, but i have no idea how to fix! Im thinking maybe should all the _setDomainName be set to the domain's? I have read conflicting advice on this.
many thanks

GA code domain A

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-7338871-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

GA code domain B

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-7338871-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'none']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
</script>
```

iframe script domain A

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var iframeLink = "domainb.com";
_gaq.push(function() {
    var pageTracker = _gat._getTrackerByName();
iframeLink = pageTracker._getLinkerUrl(iframeLink);
document.getElementById("myIFrame").src = iframeLink;   
});
</script>
```